# Assembla: Do you like Trac tickets or Assembla tickets and why?

Tags: bug-tracking, trac, assembla

I am a single developer just getting started with open source web dev (Python/Django). I signed up for a free Assembla.com account but I really don't know whether to use Trac ticketing or Assembla integrated ticketing. I have setup spaces for both to try them out, but it seems like I would need to use them for a while before I saw clear benefits either way.

As I am just starting out, I'm just working on small projects, e.g. the Django tutorial, etc.

Do you have recommendations of Trac vs. Assembla ticketing? And yes, I have Googled this without any helpful results.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not qualified to discuss "best", which is what a request for recommendations boils down to.

Trac has an extensive (and IMHO well-architected) plugin infrastructure; if you're a heavy Python developer and are interested in customizing your ticketing system (or if you aren't, and find any of the [existing plugins](http://trac-hacks.org/) useful), such may be a factor to consider.

Answer (score 2):

I've only used the Trac tickets since I'm using also the Trac wiki and the Trac subversion repository. It makes sense to be able to link back and forth between tickets, wiki pages and source code.

However the ticket user interface is very web 1.0 style: Lots of page reloading and navigation. The ticket editing page is also too long. I would certainly prefer tadalist style editing.

Perhaps a Google Spreadsheet is the way to go. It's easy to edit and sort, and you can have a Skype conference while editing the ticket list together.

Answer (score 2):

I find the Assembla tickets really good. I've not tried the Trac ones much, I was put off by the nasty interface.

From my understanding Assembla are pushing users towards their tool too, rather than Trac. I think this makes sense as it allows them to more fully integrate it with their other tools.

Answer (score 1):

I use Assembla ticketing and it works just fine... never needed anything else.
Also, right now I'm hosting some of my project at Google Code and it also has a minimal yet very useful tracking system.

Answer (score 1):

Assembla Tickets, at least the version in use now, 2y after your original question, is miles ahead of Trac. Some of the niceties: scrum orderred backlog, better user, notification, privacy management, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Just for trying littl this - littl that any hosted solution would do. If it turns out you are a real geek - for misc. reasons you would want to run your very own VPS (e.g. from slicehost, which i love). I've been using Trac for quite some time and it's a great choice if you have a single project and need only basic functionality. Recently switched to redmine which has more features and is more suitable for multi-project environment.